# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'comments.commenter_id' in 'on clause'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

Here is my query with relation, and I am fetching data with comments and with comments I need user detail too, but if I do like below I am getting the above error.

```
$type = 'success';
        $status_code = 200;
        $message = 'Posts data listed.';

        $response = Post::with(['associate:id,name,avatar', 'comments:id,commenter_id,commentable_id,comment,created_at'])
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.commenter_id');

        if (request()->query('search')) {
            // $response = $response->where("name", "LIKE", "%" . request()->query('search') . "%");
            $response = $response->search(request()->query('search'));
        };
        $response = $response->latest('posts.created_at')->paginate(5);

        return response_data($type, $status_code, $message, $response);
```

Comment: The problem is not about your code, what are your comments table columns? there is no commenter_id in that table.

Comment: it's not true, the commenter_id column is there but when I join the comments table with users it through the above error.

Comment: add belongs to the relationship in comment model with the user then pass it with in query

Comment: Please provide the full query included in the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `->with` method, eloquent will fetch `comments` after executing main query (Means `Post::...->join()`), So if you want using a table in your query, then you should use it in related query.

So use `join` in `with` method:

```php
Post::with('associate:id,name,avatar')
->with('comments',function ($query) {
    $query
        // Now you can select from users or comments
        // e.g. ->select([...,'users.any_column_you_want'])
        ->select(['comments.id','commenter_id','commentable_id','comment','created_at'])
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.commenter_id');
});
```

Check reference: [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

Check mysql join reference for a better understanding: [W3Schools Mysql Join](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join.asp)

Comment: "Call to undefined relationship [posts] on model [App\\Models\\Post].",

Comment: Sorry, this error was due to my distraction (I mistyped `posts` instead of `comments`), which I fixed (Answer updated).

Comment: I tried as you maintain but i got "Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: it is belongs to your `select` statement, because of existing two tables (`users` and `comments`) so it ambiguous for select which table id. so I change `id` to `comments.id` (Answer updated).